# Adjusting ambiguous type references on xmlns: xmlns:x and xmlns:cal attributes for precedence

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, xaml

I've the following xml name spaces referenced on my xaml. Both of them have some kind of ambiguity.

`<Window x:Class="HelloWorld.Shell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:cal="http://www.codeplex.com/prism"
    Title="Hello World" Height="300" Width="300">
    <ItemsControl Name="MainRegion" cal:RegionManager.RegionName="MainRegion" />
</Window>`

Error message thrown

> > Ambiguous type reference. A type named 'RegionManager' occurs in at least two namespaces, 'Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Regions' and 'Prism.Regions'. 
> >     Consider adjusting the assembly XmlnsDefinition attributes.

in

**HelloWorld.Desktop    HelloWorld\HelloWorld.Desktop\Shell.xaml**

Answer (score 0):

Look like you have 2 references in your project to Prism,

I guess that you've installed Prism 4 and Prism 5 on the same solution?

if so, try to remove the references for Prism 4.